# Connectycube cannot createSession on android when using react native

Tags: android, react-native, connectycube

I am using react native 0.71 recently and connected to the connect cube's react native sdk. When I call `await ConnectyCube. createSession (params)` on iOS, everything is normal. But when I debug in Android Studio, createSession will return failure. I don't know what happened. Can someone help me? Thank you very much. Here is my development environment:

[env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szn05.png)

I tried using Postman to directly call the API of connectycube, but still reported an error:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKQVQ.png)

url: https://api.connectycube.com/session.json

data:`{"application_id": 5032, "auth_key": "6Be2zh-rqaWnFD8", "nonce": 4693, "signature": "4a903cc3e6394f6749ab419df76cae68ccb8657f", "timestamp": 1691170124, "user": {"login": "hello@englishtalkabout.com", "password": "11111111"}}`

Edited: I used the official RNChat demo of connectycube and reported the same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something wrong with `timestamp`. Different between `timestamp` in request and server more then 60 seconds. Check your device date settings.

https://developers.connectycube.com/server/auth?id=create-session